# OnClickListener in a dialog button is called twice with a long processing

Tags: android, dialog, onclick

I have a bug on my application, it looks really strange but it is easy to reproduce.

Try this code on an activity :

```
public    int    myIncrement = 0;

protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int i, Bundle args)
    {
        if (i == DIALOG_TEST_MY_BUG)
        {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Test");

            builder.setNegativeButton("Test", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
                {
                    Log.i("Test", "<- myIncrement : " + myIncrement);
                    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
                        myIncrement ++;
                    Log.i("Test", "-> myIncrement : " + myIncrement);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

When you show this dialog, it's ok. When you click on the button "Test", it's ok. The log shows :

```
<- myIncrement : 0
-> myIncrement : 1000000
```

But if you click repetitively on the button "Test", the onClickListener will be called 2 or more times :

```
<- myIncrement : 0
-> myIncrement : 1000000
<- myIncrement : 1000000
-> myIncrement : 2000000...
```

Here this exemple is just to let you understand my problem. The equivalent of

```
                    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
                        myIncrement ++;
```

is a long processing with file writting and a view change, and an other with synchronisation on a server. I tried lots of changes, like change a boolean in the onClick method, but without success.

Please, check your answer before proposing. Please also try this on your applications, when a click causes a long processing, try to click it many times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to start a long running task in the UI thread, which is completely prohibited. It may cause you bugs like this and ANRs too, if the task runs longer then 5 seconds. So for any long running tasks you should create a separate thread. I'd reccomend using the [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) class since it's very simple to use and to synchronize with the UI thread to show your users that your application is not stuck. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Change to this:

```
private AlertDialog builder = null;
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int i, Bundle args)
 {
     if (i == DIALOG_TEST_MY_BUG)
     {
         if(builder != null && builder.isShowing()
             return; // prevent multiple dialog instances
         builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
         builder.setTitle("Test");
```

Comment: The question has nothing to do with multiple dialog instances.